# Get Date or NOW() Sql And convert to int... then do where

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT * FROM `artc_ai1ec_events` where `start`=1415055600;
```

I have this simple question for u guys...

I need do this query... 
'start' is a datetime field... its save in mysql format int(10);
i need **compare** that **field** with the **actual date** ONLY...

i think something like this

```
SELECT * FROM `artc_ai1ec_events` where `start`=convert(int, now());
```

need ur help

Comment: When you say compare do you mean find the difference or to filter results in the time between the two dates?

Comment: Can you give some example data of your start field?

Comment: ok i give u 3 examples: start=1407470400, start=1408053600, start=1408161600;

Comment: Please do not edit your question to include a new problem. Instead, create a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM artc_ai1ec_events` where `start`  = UNIX_TIMESTAMP( now() ) ;
```

Comment: mr. Can u help me with the new problem

Comment: Please tell me, I will try my best

Answer (score 1):

how about doing the convert the int to datetime rather than the datetime now() to int.

```
SELECT * FROM artc_ai1ec_events` where  FROM_UNIXTIME('Start') = now()
```